# Polars filtering by unique groups

Tags: pylint, python-polars

I'm trying to filter by unique values of a group of columns and created a nested dictionary with each one.

```py
def create_nested_dict_polars(df, key_cols):
    """
    Converts the DataFrame to a list of dictionaries after grouping

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : pl.DataFrame
        DataFrame to be converted to a nested dictionary.
    key_cols : list
        List of columns to be used as keys for grouping.

    Returns
    -------
    dict
        Nested dictionary created from the DataFrame.
    """

    df = df.clone()
    groups = df.unique(subset=key_cols)
    groups = groups.select(key_cols)

    nested_dict = {}

    # Iterate through each group, creating the nested dictionary structure
    for row in groups.to_dicts():
        filter_condition = reduce(
            lambda x, y: x & pl.col(y).eq(row[y]), key_cols, pl.lit(True)
        )

        records = df.filter(filter_condition).to_dicts()

        set_nested_value(nested_dict, list(row.values()), records)

    return nested_dict


def set_nested_value(nested_dict, keys, value):
    """
    Sets a value in a nested dictionary structure, creating intermediate dictionaries as needed.

    :param nested_dict: The outermost dictionary.
    :param keys: A list of keys representing the path to the target location.
    :param value: The value to set at the target location.
    """
    for key in keys[:-1]:
        nested_dict = nested_dict.setdefault(key, {})
    nested_dict[keys[-1]] = value
```

I don't understand why pylint is telling me that in the reduce line:

Cell variable row defined in loop.

When I go to the help of pylint it says that the problem is I could be using the same variable on each loop at the end.

How I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the code work as intended? The warning seems to be about the usage of `row` inside a lambda in a for loop. It could be a [false positive](https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/issues/3107) as you're also calling it inside the loop. Can you share a runnable example? It seems like perhaps this could be done with a more "Polars-native" approach.

Comment: @jqurious don't they need to include `row=row` in their lambda?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor As they're calling the lambda immediately inside the loop (and not using LazyFrames) I believe there should be no binding issue.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor  I put inside the lambda the row and the warning dissapeared.
Anyway I tried both versions and the result was the same.

Thanks!